# How to load a .py script directly with evaluate.load?

Tags: python, metrics, huggingface, huggingface-evaluate

If I have a script like this https://huggingface.co/spaces/evaluate-metric/frugalscore/blob/main/frugalscore.py and save it as `fgscore.py` with a directory locally like:

```
./
  my_script.py
  fgscore/
      fgscore.py
```

And in my_script.py, I can do something like:

```
import evaluate


mt_metrics = evaluate.load("fgscore")

sources = ["안녕하세요 저는 당신의 아버지입니다", "일반 케노비"]
predictions = ["hello here I am your father", "general kenobi"]
references = ["hello there I am your father", "general yoda"]
results = mt_metrics.compute(predictions=predictions,
                             references=references)

print(results)
```

Looking at the `evaluate.load()` function, https://github.com/huggingface/evaluate/blob/main/src/evaluate/loading.py#L688, it states:

```
path (`str`):
    Path to the evaluation processing script with the evaluation builder. Can be either:
        - a local path to processing script or the directory containing the script (if the script has the same name as the directory),
            e.g. `'./metrics/rouge'` or `'./metrics/rouge/rouge.py'`
        - a evaluation module identifier on the HuggingFace evaluate repo e.g. `'rouge'` or `'bleu'` that are in either `'metrics/'`,
            `'comparisons/'`, or `'measurements/'` depending on the provided `module_type`
```

#### Is there a reason to do `{name}/{name}.py` for using the path arguments in `evaluate.load()`?

#### Is there a way to override such that I can point the evaluate directly to the `.py` file? E.g. `evaluate.load("fgscore.py")`

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to repeat the name and a path when using `evaluate.load()`, you can have the directory structure like this:

```
./
  my_script.py
  fgscore.py
```

And in the `my_script.py` do this:

```
import evaluate


mt_metrics = evaluate.load("./fgscore.py")

sources = ["안녕하세요 저는 당신의 아버지입니다", "일반 케노비"]
predictions = ["hello here I am your father", "general kenobi"]
references = ["hello there I am your father", "general yoda"]
results = mt_metrics.compute(predictions=predictions,
                             references=references)

print(results)
```